# Enabling refreshing for specific html elements only

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I would like to know how I can only refresh a specific element in my website, instead of the whole web page? The element I'm talking about is a flash application that loads quite slow and may experience connection timeouts. I want to enable the user to only refresh that element/falsh app. How do i do that? Below I have an Ajax function that updates an HTML element but not sure how to apply it to my situation.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
```

Comment: why not make the flash refresh the contents within it? instead of having AJAX load the swf into the DOM again and again

Comment: Good point, but I do not have control over the flash file. It is a complex app that is developed by someone else.If I understand you incorrectly, please correct me

Comment: Could you put it in an iFrame? I think that setting the location.href of an iFrame will cause it to refresh.

Comment: yes i can put it in an iFrame...currently it is in an object tag

Comment: as I said, I basically want an option for the user to refresh only the flash object on click/on request instead of reloading the whole page again

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function reload(){
    var container = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML= content; 
    
   //this line is to watch the result in console , you can remove it later 
    console.log("Refreshed"); 
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: reload()">Click to Reload</a>
    <div id="yourDiv">The content that you want to refresh/reload</div>
```

Hope it works. Let me know

Comment: This would remove any event listeners on that element. Use it with caution.

Answer (score 5):

Try creating a javascript function which runs this:

```
document.getElementById("youriframeid").contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Or maybe use an HTML workaround:

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
      <a href="pagename.htm" target="middle">Refresh iframe</a>
      <p>
        <iframe src="pagename.htm" name="middle">
      </p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Both might be what you're looking for...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Javascript solution you posted: how exactly does that work, is it automatically activated or can it be requested/activated by the user?

Comment: Hi Dexter.. If you can see, there's a link "Refresh iframe". If the user clicks this, it will refresh the iFrame. So it requires user activation / intervention.

Comment: This helped me out with an issue I was having for UI automation (or all things). Since the <iframe> was loaded dynamically, the automation framework couldn't "see" the dynamically added code without adding this refresh step first. Thanks for this tip. Very happy to vote this up!

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your script:

```
$("#YourElement").html(htmlData);
```

I do this in my table refreshment.

Answer (score 0):

try to empty your innerHtml everytime.
just like this:

```js
Element.innerHtml="";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for me, instead of reloading whole page just reload a div was:

```
$( "#your_div_ID" ).load(window.location.href + " #your_div_ID" );
```

I built it in ajax function, when response assessed.