# Refresh html Object by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, base64

I have an object :

```
<object id="pdfViewer" data="<?=$b64?>" type="application/pdf" title="document" width="100%" height="800"></object>
```

$b64 is string like this : $b64 = "data:application/pdf;base64,**base64 string**".

On the first page load, the pdf is displayed in chrome and firefox, not in IE (without errors).

I refresh this object by ajax with this code :

```
var $pdf = $("#pdfViewer");
$pdf.attr('data','data:application/pdf;base64,'+bin64Corrected);
```

It works on firefox, not on chrome (it was working in a previous version) and still not IE :D.

I've search for a solution, tried this :

```
$pdf.load('data:application/pdf;base64,'+bin64Corrected);
```

It wasn't working.

Thanks for the help !

**EDIT**

It now works on chrome, I had to change this code to fix the javascript loading part :

```
newObject = '<object id="pdfViewer" data="data:application/pdf;base64,'+bin64Corrected+'" type="application/pdf" title="document" width="100%" height="800"></object>';
$pdf.parent().append(newObject);
```

But it's still not working in IE, the only way I can get it working is to do this :

```
<object id="pdfViewer" data="site/displayPdf" type="application/pdf" title="document" width="100%" height="800"></object>
```

**site/displayPdf** is a url that sends pdf bin data with PDF headers.

So does any of you know if it's impossible to load pdf object in IE based on base64 string ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this solution work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841239/enabling-refreshing-for-specific-html-elements-only

Comment: nope, thanks anyway :/

Comment: Perhaps you could instead embed the PDF in an iframe, and [reload that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript).

Comment: I can't cause the pdf is loaded with a base 64 string I receive in an ajax call :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the Max length of JSON returns?

In your web.config, find this or add it if you don't have it:

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```

See if that helps.

Comment: nope but the fact that it's working on firefox made me think it's not a server issue, right ?

Comment: did you at least try it?

Comment: it's written in php so there's no limit for the json