# Making links dynamically

Tags: html, ajax

I have a HTML page. In this page there is an Ajax that connects to the server and recieves the necessary informations to make a link. Using these informations it creates an "a" tag with appropriate href attribute and append this tag to an existing element of the page. The text of the link appears but is not clickable. (Mouse does not change on it). But when I save the page on my disk and reopen it, the links are fine. What is the problem?
The script is as following:

```
$(document).ready(loadDoc());
    function loadDoc(){
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      makeNavigation(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/Head/Explore/ErebosPlain", true);
  xhttp.send();
    }   
    function makeNavigation(xml){
    var i = 0;
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml.responseText,"text/xml");   
    categs = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Category");
    for (i=1; i < categs.length ; i++) {

    a = xmlDoc.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href","?currentnode=" + categs[i].getAttribute("id"));
    p = document.createTextNode(categs[i].getAttribute("preferredName"));
    a.appendChild(p);
    el = document.getElementById("mainnav");
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(a)
    el.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
```

And the Html part to be affected:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><xsl:value-of select="./Division/@preferredName"></xsl:value-of></a>
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainnav">
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: It'd be nice to have some code to test out and debug. Right now, the answer to this question is just a matter of trial and error. Like @nmnsud said, can you please add some code.

Comment: the output: <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aztech</a></div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainnav"><li><a href="?currentnode=0">consequat metus</a></li><li><a href="?currentnode=2">volutpat</a></li><li><a href="?currentnode=3">condimentum</a></li></ul>
         </div>
      </nav>

Comment: The solution is to refresh just the div.
Thanks to the poste: [Enabling refreshing for specific html elements only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841239/enabling-refreshing-for-specific-html-elements-only)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're putting the url in the

```
<a href='[url text goes here]'>[clickable text here]</a>
```

there's not much reason it shouldn't work if you have the syntax right