# reload javascript variable (string value) into div with button click

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I have a cognito form embeded to my site like this:

```
<div id="magic" class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/formlink"></script>
<script>
Cognito.load("forms", { id: "34", entry: {"textboxname": magictext }});
</script>
</div>
```

This is form is loaded empty when I navigate to this page which is fine.
On the other parts of my page the user can add some josn stringified text which is goes into a javascript variable called `magictext`. Now I would like to add a button to my page which will reload/refresh the *magic div* and update the magictext in the form based on the user input.
I have this script below, it looks like is refreshing the form, but does not add the `magictext` string into the textbox.. on click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload(){
            var container = document.getElementById("magic");
            var content = container.innerHTML;
            container.innerHTML= content;
        }
</script>

<a href="javascript: reload()">Reload</a>
```

Comment: the reload function doesn't make sense

Comment: I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841239/enabling-refreshing-for-specific-html-elements-only

Answer (score 1):

You are reading `container.innerHTML` into `content` and then writing it back into `container.innerHTML`. This is not going to do anything.

You probably want to instead do something like this in your `reload()`:

```
document.getElementById("magictext").value = magictext;
```

Comment: I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841239/enabling-refreshing-for-specific-html-elements-only

Comment: That code from the answer you linked only kinda reloads the element. I do not think it will help in your case. Have you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: I tried. Its generate error, says: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at reload (index.html:87)

Comment: You might need to modify the selection code if your textbox does not have the id `magictext` like I falsely assumed.